# Can't save tags using ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

Via console I can save tags but via a form in View I can not save tags.

In the model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user
    has_paper_trail
    acts_as_taggable

    @tags = Person.tag_counts_on(:tags)

    def admin_permalink
    admin_post_path(self)
  end
end
```

I've [read](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast) that I should include `attr_accessible :tag_list` in the Model, but doing so causes an error in Rails 4. My form partial has

```
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'tag_counts_on(:tags)'
Try 'acts_as_taggable_on :tags'

---

[Edited]
I solved it by fixing lots of deprecated syntax and incorrect use of your ruby code.

**1.**
First of all, the cause of that error was because you didn't properly whitelist
**:tag_list** attribute.

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :twitter, :facebook, :instagram, :vine, :tag_list => [])
end
```

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :twitter, :facebook, :instagram, :vine, :tag_list)
end
```

**2.** I think you followed some kind of tutorials right?
 I saw the similar code from one of tut articles just right, and it was written on 2012.
Following tuts is good practice, but always check the date.

**3.** I suggest you to upgrade Rails to v4.1.0 at least
because your Active Admin gem complains the support for below Rails v4.1.0  will be dropped soon.

**4.** I found the label had incorrect attribute, which is :tags, so I changed it to :tag_list.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</div>
```

[image: preview]

You may clone this repo from: **https://github.com/seoyoochan/adriangrantdotorg-urbanbook**

Comment: @ace973 please show me the error log and the git repo of that gem.

Comment: [here's the repo](https://github.com/adriangrantdotorg/urbanbook), thanks @seoyoochan

Comment: Thanks @seeyoochan - I upgraded to the latest stable versions of Ruby and Rails and implemented your suggestions. Editing existing Person works but when creating new ones I get this error **undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007f95ed8dd990>** in app/controllers/people_controller.rb:49:in `block in create'
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:48:in `create'

Comment: One of important habits developers should have is always checking the error log thoroughly. It says 'undefined method each for User class', which means it is user instance did not exist( nil value). Go to 'create' method at Line 48. Try to find in which the problem is